# npm run graphql-deploy command stuck in Sanity

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, sanity

When I am running, the command `npm run graphql-deploy` in my local it stuck at `lerna info Executing command in 1 package: "npm run graphql-deploy"`. Not moving forward.

And if I run same command in studio folder it stuck at:
GraphQL API deployed to:
https://qht1v59y.api.sanity.io/v1/graphql/development/default

Please refer screenshot

[image]

So due to this I am not able to deploy my changes. What's the issue here. How to fix this ?

Comment: I just came across the same issue and didn't solve it yet. However, the login to sanity is not working anymore either, I suspect that may be the cause. Maybe that is the case for you too? I'm currently stuck on the login issue and following this :)

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue is there any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you never found a fix for this, it was merged into `@sanity/cli`. I just updated it and seems tow work fine now.

https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/pull/2987